# SDL Drawing lines

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl-2

I'm trying to add something resembling a debug draw in my engine built on SDL and Modern OpenGL. The way rendering works right now is using Modern OpenGL (so no SDL methods are used in drawing the sprites I want to the screen). Here's some of the code that makes this work:

```
// Main Rendering loop
glClearDepth(1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

colorProgram.bind();

std::sort(objectsWithGraphicsComponentInThisScene.begin(), objectsWithGraphicsComponentInThisScene.end(), sortByRenderDepth);

for (size_t t = 0; t < objectsWithGraphicsComponentInThisScene.size(); ++t)
{
    // set texture
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, objectsWithGraphicsComponentInThisScene[t]->getComponent<GraphicsComponent>()->getTexture());

    GLint texLocation = colorProgram.getUniformLocation("texSampler");
    glUniform1i(texLocation, 0);

    glm::mat4 rot = glm::rotate(glm::mat4x4(1.0f), objectsWithGraphicsComponentInThisScene[t]->getComponent<GraphicsComponent>()->getRotation(), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
    glm::mat4 scale = glm::scale(glm::mat4x4(1.0f), glm::vec3(objectsWithGraphicsComponentInThisScene[t]->getComponent<GraphicsComponent>()->getScale().x, objectsWithGraphicsComponentInThisScene[t]->getComponent<GraphicsComponent>()->getScale().y, 1.0f));

    glm::mat4 trans;
    trans = glm::translate(glm::mat4x4(1.0f), glm::vec3(objectsWithGraphicsComponentInThisScene[t]->getPosition().x, objectsWithGraphicsComponentInThisScene[t]->getPosition().y, 0));
    GLint transMatLocation = colorProgram.getUniformLocation("transformMatrix");
    trans *= rot * scale;
    glUniformMatrix4fv(transMatLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(trans));

    // set camera Matrix
    GLint projMatLocation = colorProgram.getUniformLocation("projectionMatrix");
    glm::mat4 cameraMatrix = camera->getCameraMatrix();
    glUniformMatrix4fv(projMatLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(cameraMatrix));

    // This runs the Sprite::draw method per object in the current scene
    objectsWithGraphicsComponentInThisScene[t]->getComponent<GraphicsComponent>()->getSprite()->draw();

    // unbind all
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}

colorProgram.unbind();

// swap front and back buffer
SDL_GL_SwapWindow(BaseSDLWindowManager::get()->getWindow());
```

Here's the code in the `getSprite()->draw()` method:

```
void Sprite::draw()
{
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

// arguments:
// 1. Which VertexAttribArray
// 2. How many items per attribute
// 3. Which type are the items in the array
// ...
//5. stride, if the data is interleaved (pos, color, ...)

// position
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, position));

//color
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_TRUE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, color));

// uv
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, uv));

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

Now what I want to do is, add something so that I can render simple lines and such (or rectangles, simple shapes). I've tried putting this kind of code all over the rendering process: (but before the `SDL_GL_SwapWindow()`)

```
//Render green outlined quad
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(BaseSDLWindowManager::get()->getRenderer(), 255, 0, 0, 255);
SDL_RenderDrawLine(BaseSDLWindowManager::get()->getRenderer(), 0, 0, 100, 100);
```

but I'm not getting any rendering done with this. Nothing is showing. Since I'm kind of new to Modern OpenGL and SDL rendering I'd like to know where I should put this code or how I should change it so that it does render. I have no clue where to start looking

Comment: maybe start with a tutorial on [drawing line primitives in opengl](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2013/05/13/opengl-101-drawing-primitives/), or is something forcing you to use SDL?

Comment: Thanks. I'm reading through that. Nothing is forcing me to use SDL but I've started with it and I think it's going to be more work to switch to something else then to try and understand the current problem. Do you have any alternatives maybe?